# Как сделать так, чтобы из БД удалялись нужные посты?

Tags: php, html, laravel, blade

И так, я продолжаю разбираться с Laravel, на этот раз я затупил над удалением записей из БД, а именно:

Значится в наличии имеется таблица с постами, которую я вывожу через контроллер в представление, используя пагинацию:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Posts;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function form()
    {
        $del = DB::table('posts');

        return view('posts.form', [
            'title' => 'form title', 'paginate' => Posts::paginate(15), 'del' => $del
        ]);
    }
}
```

В этом самом представлении я пытаюсь сделать таблицу, в которой буду выводить все посты с их id на экран. С этим проблем нет, но далее я хочу добавить колонку таблицы в которой будут стоять ссылки на удаление соответствующих записей:

```
<x-layout>
    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ $title }}
    </x-slot>
    <a href="/post/add/">добавить пост</a>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>text</th>
            <th>delete</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($paginate as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->text }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ $del->where('id', $post->id)->delete() }}">Удалить</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{ $paginate->links() }}
</x-layoit>
```

И с этим у меня начинаются проблемы. Так как записи удаляются по порядку сверху вниз, на какую бы строку я не нажимал, удаляются они в общем-то, даже если я ни на какую строку не нажимаю, а просто обновляю страницу. Собственно, буду рад, если объясните, что я делаю не так.

Comment: @Simon , спасибо, я обязательно ознакомлюсь, ниже уже объяснили, что я сделал не так, но за ссылку спасибо, кажется этого я ещё не читал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы вызываете удаление записей при формировании шаблона, поэтому записи у вас и удаляются при обновлении страницы.

Т.е. когда вы вставляете в шаблон код

```
$del->where('id', $post->id)->delete()
```

то этот код выполяняется сразу, при формировании страницы, а вовсе не при нажатии на ссылку, как вы предполагаете.

Чтобы удалять записи при клике по ссылке, вам надо чтобы эта ссылка вела на отдельный action контроллера и уже в этом экшене удалять запись по id, который будет передан в параметре ссылки.

Т.е. ссылка может выглядеть так

```
    <td>
        <a href="/post/delete?id ={{ $post->id }}">Удалить</a>
    </td>
```

А уже в контроллер PostsController добавляете новую функцию для обработки URI /post/delete и в ней получаете id из запроса и по нему удаляете, а потом редиректите пользователя назад на страницу со списком.

В дальнейшем можн осделать удаление через AJAX и т.п. вещи.

Comment: не надо гет-запросами удалят данные

Comment: @teran а почему? Можете предложить свой вариант легкий для понимания начинающему?

Comment: потому что get-запросы предназначены для получения данных, а не их изменения. Для изменения post/put.

Comment: @teran - а ок. Т.е. чисто религиозные причины - понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Вы сделали не ссылку на удаление записи, а вызываете метод QueryBuilder'а, что и вызывает удаление записей в процессе загрузки страницы. Для удаления понадобится добавить роут (что-то вроде `/posts/1/delete`, где 1 - id поста) и добавить в контроллер нужный метод

роут:

```
Route::post('posts/{postId}/delete', [PostsController::class, 'deletePost']);
```

метод:

```
public function deletePost(Request $request, int $postId)
{
    DB::table('posts')->where('id', $postId)->delete();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, разорался!